# Including Java 1.8 in classpath without specifying build

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am working on a project with two other people. We are all on the same version of Eclipse (Mars.1), but we occasionally have different versions of the Java library on our machines solely because one of us has upgraded and the others haven't (yet). This is transient, but clearly causes build problems.

Here is what the .classpath looks like (NOTE: I manually inserted a line break on the line that references the JRE_CONTAINER to help you avoid scrolling the line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="res"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/
        org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 8 [1.8.0_25]">
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
            </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
    </classpath>
```

As you can see, the line specifies the build. Is it possible to specify it in such a way that specific build is not included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that happened to us as well, the solution was to remove the `.classpath` file from the code repository (Git, SVN, etc) and put it in the ignored files list (`.gitignore` file or whatever you use).

Also remove the `.classpath` file from every developer's workspace, and Eclipse will regenerate this file specifically for your environment.

This will avoid any further issues with different minor java versions.

**Edit**: Since you mentioned you are not using any build system, here is a minimal `pom.xml` so that you can convert your project into a Maven project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your-organization</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-project-or-module-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>NameOfTheProject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Reference your libraries here -->
        <!-- Maven will download them automatically :O -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's an [Introduction to the standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and here's a guide on [Specifying resource directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

Comment: How did you get around build issues then? We're using the .classpath to point to folders like /res (containing resources like images and such). When a change is made, do you have to manually have all of your "team" update their classpath respectively? NOTE: I realize we should be using Maven or Ant or something, but my two partners in this have zero experience with those tools and we don't have time to introduce it (this is for a semester project)

Comment: @Greg we use Maven. You should try it, it is very easy to get a minimal setup. You just have to add a minimal `pom.xml` file to the root of your project and tell Eclipse this is a Maven project. Option2: go to New Project > Maven Project, select one of the default archetypes and import your code.